How to find fixed points of this radial map $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}^2$
I have learned that finding fixed points of a map is usually done by setting the map $f(x)=x$. However, for this radial map $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}^2$
$$F\begin{pmatrix}\theta_1\\ \theta_2\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}\theta_1+\epsilon\sin{\theta_1}\\ \theta_2+\epsilon\sin\theta_2\cos\theta_1\end{pmatrix}$$
I am not sure at all.
The fixed points are apparently, due to Devaney, $(0,\pi)$, $(\pi,\pi)$, $(\pi,0)$ and $(0,0)$.
How are these found?
Thanks

To find them you need to solve $f(x) = x$ (this is what it means to be a fixpoint). In this case $x$ is a 2D vector so you you get the two equations $\theta_1 = \theta_1 + \epsilon\sin\theta_1$ and  $\theta_2 = \theta_2 + \epsilon\sin\theta_2\cos\theta_1$ which are not too hard to solve.

Let $F\colon\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}^2$ given by
$$F\left(\theta_1,\theta_2\right)=\left(\theta_1+\epsilon\sin{\theta_1}, \theta_2+\epsilon\sin\theta_2\cos\theta_1\right). $$
You want to solve $F(\theta_1,\theta_2)=(\theta_1,\theta_2)$ which is equivalent to $\left(\epsilon\sin{\theta_1}, \epsilon\sin\theta_2\cos\theta_1\right)=(0,0).$ Assume that $\epsilon\neq0$, the first coordinates tells you that $\theta_1=k\pi$ for any integer $k$. Report this in the second coordinate, you obtain $\sin\theta_2=0$ and hence  that $\epsilon\neq0$, the first coordinates tells you that $\theta_2=\ell\pi$ for any integer $\ell$.
The set of fixed point of $F$ is then the infinite set
$$
\left\{(k\pi,\ell\pi)\colon (k,\ell)\in\mathbb{Z}^2\right\}. 
$$
The four points you mention is then the fixed points of the restriction of $F$ to $[0,2\pi[^2$.

Thanks Emmanuel!
